# Load form data in JavaScript and run something client side

Tags: javascript, python

The original framework of my app (using Python) is below:

1. user key in keywords in forms.
2. App use the data in forms as parameter to get some results from third-party website.
3. The result which is from third-party website will be analyzed in my app.
4. Then show the result of analyze to user.

But there are some problems between my app and third-party website, so I want to change the framework of my app.

1. user key in keywords in forms.
2. store the keywords which in forms as cookie.
3. automatically download one javascript which in my app (website), and run the javascript in user's computer.
4. the javascript will get result from third-party website, and then sent the result to my app.
5. my app will analyze the result (from third-party website) and then show the result of analyze to user.

I want to know how can I do this, or what keyword should I search in Google.

Comment: Sorry but your questions makes very little sense at the moment. You seem to misunderstand the whole concept of JavaScript. If you can explain better what you need you will likely get more help here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I change the describe of my question. If you have experience in this, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Jimmy, can you clarify what the problems are between your app and the 3rd party API?

Comment: @Jimmy no problem, now it's much better. If the third party website does not expose `JSONP` service then you will have to use server side language like PHP or ASP.NET to send the data. If it does expose JSONP service, you can use the jQuery [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

Comment: @ Shadow Wizard : Thank you for your reply. is this method run in server side or client side ? Seems like this method is the best way to solve my problem. The third-party website is [Twitter Search API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method:-search) and they provide the JSON format to catch.

Comment: @Daniel Schaffer : Actually I build my app in Google App Engine(GAE) and the third-party website is Twitter Search. But Twitter ban the request from GAE.

Comment: BTW, I use Python to implement this App, so if there is methods using Python, that will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unclear what you are looking for. If the question is about server push keywords are WebSockets,Socket.io,Ajax,Comet,Bayeux to start with

Comment: The original framework of my application is : User key in words in forms in my app -> my app will parser a web and get the result back -> then my app will analyze the result and show back to user. But there are some problem in the web and my app. So I want to change way to get the result. So I want to use javascript to store the data which is in form, then auto download the javascript to user's computer, and then run the javascript in user's computer, get the result(from third-party web) back. At last, send the result to my app, analyze and then show to user. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Jimmy what do you mean by "web"? **The World Wide Web**, or **a website**?

Comment: It's means website. I figure out that I can store the data as cookie. And use the javascript to read the cookie and run. And the remaining question is how can I let browser download javascript automatically and run as cookie as parameters.